# getting a bank card (virtual, prepaid or debit) in Argentinian Pesos, from abroad, for foreign citizens

Tags: payment-cards, argentina

Is there a way to register for an Argentinian bank card, or prepaid card, or virtual card in Argentinian Pesos, for people that are not citizens/residents of Argentina ?
Should pass IIN validation as listed: https://www.creditcardvalidator.org/country/ar-argentina

I've looked at Revolut, TransferWise, but they don't support this.

some context: Looking to buy a couple internal flights in Argentina. Tickets from Norwegian are cheaper in Argentinian Pesos than in USD or GBP. But at the last booking step, there's a check for the bank card number, and it only accepts Argentinian bank cards ("Los pagos en ARS solo se pueden efectuar con tarjetas emitidas en Argentina. Selecciona una moneda o tarjeta de pago distintas.")

Comment: Google Translate renders the error message as "ARS payments can only be made with cards issued in Argentina." So focusing on the _currency_ is a red herring -- they care not about which currency the underlying account is kept in, but purely about _where the card is issued_. It's for purposes of **market segregation**, not motivated by anything to do with the mechanics of paying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it isn't possible. You will have to provide a national identity document (DNI) with a minimum validity of 12 months and also have to provide a tax id (CUIL).

Even with all of that mentioned above, most banks still won't accept you as customer because of internal policies.

Source: trust me dude, I made it after lots of blood, sweat and tears.

#### Update January 2021

[Banco Credicoop](https://www.bancocredicoop.coop/personas) accepted a friend of mine as customer and opened them an account (*Caja de ahorro*) just with a valid CUIL, even without a DNI. However, ANSES won't give you a CUIL without starting the immigration process at *Dirección Nacional de Migraciones*. They will you provide with a  *Radicación Precaria* thats a requirement to get a CUIL.

Answer (score 6):

Ask someone you know well from Argentina to buy the ticket for you, bring USD with you and reimburse them with cash. Everybody wins.

Unfortunately Argentinean monetary regulation (if it's possible to name it so) calls for such manual transactions.

Comment: Having been to Argentina for a couple of weeks after asking the question, the worst one can do is NOT have USD cash - it will cause a lot of pain, as ATM withdrawals have ridiculous limits and fees, and the cheaper ATM network seems to be out of cash at any time, even in the capital.

Comment: Fortunately, you can always go to Uruguay and withdraw USD from ATMs there.